# Split em aspas simples '

Tags: c#

Tenho uma string onde existem aspas simples (') e gostaria de fazer um split
porém ao colocar, `''');`, ele quebra o código.

```
splitString = splitLines[i].Split(' ', ',', ';', '"', '(', ')', '!', '?', ':', '…', '„', '“', '¿', '¡');
```

Comment: Não conheço muito C# mas não é só escapar (\')?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Da forma que está você gerará um erro de sintaxe.

Você pode dar um scape `\'`:

```
string[] resultado = x.Split(new char[] { '\'' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Resultado: {0},{1}", resultado[0], resultado[1]));
```

Ou ao invés de passar uma array de char como parâmetro você pode utiliza string:

```
string[] resultado2 = x.Split(new string[] { "'" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Resultado2: {0},{1}", resultado2[0], resultado2[1]));
```

Exemplo Online: [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q633NJ)

Método [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)